# Understanding :%!markdown VIM command

Tags: vim

[Here](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vim-koans/) you can found the following Vim command:

```
:%!markdown
```

I know there's a 'similar' command to find/replace

```
:%s/OLD/NEW
```

But I suspect that they have nothing to do

Can someone explain the first command?

Comment: That's a motion command (`%`) followed by the `!` command.  Try `:help !`

Comment: @larsks That's not correct. Yes, `%` is a motion command, but `:%` is an ex command range (see `:help :%`).

Comment: Eh, it was close, and this question is still off topic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%!markdown
```

---

`%`: is another form of `1,$` it is the range of all lines of the file

`!`: this exclamation point is for executing an external command

[`markdown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/markdown): this command is for changing the text to html form

So that command is nothing than a **filter** that transform your text to html form. You can use a vim command that generate that by typing `:%TOhtml`

---

For more see `:help filter`, `:help :!`, `:help range`, `:help TOhtml`

Comment: One clarification, :%!markdown and :%TOhtml do not do the same thing.  `TOhtml` creates HTML of the current text with syntax highlighting to match what you see in VIM, while `markdown` translates text in a particular "markdown" format to HTML.  See https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax